# Prestashop 1.6 Cart recovery after 3DSecure redirect

Tags: php, prestashop

I am building a payment gateway module based on the Authorize.net (aim) module.  The issue is that after 3DSecure validation, it redirects back to the website, but the cart is not in context, I think.

Before I am redirecting, I am saving the cart id to the session.

It throws the following error:

"Cart cannot be loaded or an order has already been placed using this cart"

This is triggered by:

```
if (Validate::isLoadedObject($this->context->cart) && $this->context->cart->OrderExists() == false)
```

on line 188 of classes/PaymentModule.php

How can I load/reload the cart?

Thanks

Jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many payment modules, Prestashop create order before bank redirect with missing payment status and wait bank confirmation to update order.

If you want still regenerate cart, you can do that with the submitReorder functionnality in ParentOrderController.

```
        $oldCart = new Cart(Order::getCartIdStatic($id_order, $this->context->customer->id));
        $duplication = $oldCart->duplicate();
        if (!$duplication || !Validate::isLoadedObject($duplication['cart'])) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Sorry. We cannot renew your order.');
        } elseif (!$duplication['success']) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Some items are no longer available, and we are unable to renew your order.');
        } else {
            $this->context->cookie->id_cart = $duplication['cart']->id;
            $context = $this->context;
            $context->cart = $duplication['cart'];
            CartRule::autoAddToCart($context);
            $this->context->cookie->write();
            if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1) {
                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc');
            }
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');
        }
```

Comment: - how do I save the order before redirect - Google isn't being helpful